# Gradle cannot find prefix version transitive dependency which does not exist

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, versioning, transitive-dependency

I have a multi-module `gradle` project where in a module I add dependencies in `compile` configuration on runtime.

Those dependencies fetch a transitive dependency with a version prefix that does not exist.

So case is like this

```
compile 'group:moduleA:version.+'
```

This `moduleA` downloads `moduleB` with same `version.+` prefix notation and that downloads another `moduleC` with same prefix notation, `moduleC` is present in artifactory with version 10 and above and 8 and below, so there are no versions which are number 9, and gradle insist on finding `moduleC` with version 9, it doesn't fetch versions above or below it.

How can I make gradle fetch another version if the version its trying to find is not there?

Please comment for any clarification and thanks for helping.

EDIT: Want to clarify that `+` in version part is not resolving to a number which is correct and present on artifactory, like `9.1` or `9.12`.

`gradle` determines this version, which is incorrect like `9.1` is present but it resolves to `9.2` or some other number which is not there.

EDIT2: Task which is used to fetch dependencies and then add them in `compile` configuration.

```
task addAdditionalDependencies {
    doLast {
        Object slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(api.jsonResponse())
        Set<String> dependencyNames = configurations.compile.dependencies.collect { it.name }
        List<Map<String, String>> artifactPaths = slurper.results.collect {
            String[] pathSegments = it.path.split('/')
            if (!dependencyNames.contains(pathSegments[1]) && project.name != pathSegments[1]) {
                [group: pathSegments[0],
                 name: pathSegments[1],
                 version: "version.+",
                 configuration: 'compile']
            } else [:]
        }
        artifactPaths.each {
            if (!it.isEmpty()) {
                project.dependencies.add('compile', it)
            }
        }
        // we have to call this because app does not have any source files and so compileJava does not download
        // dependencies
        configurations.compile.files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a version like `9.+`, Gradle will looks for all version that matches the prefix, that is the part *before* the `+`.

There is however no way to make Gradle ignore that part in case no such version exist.

If the version of `moduleC` can be anything, then you could simply use `+` without any prefix.

Note that doing something like that could expose you to breakage in a build even though nothing changed, aside from a new version of `moduleC` being published.

You could also combine this dynamic version resolution with [dependency locking](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/dependency_locking.html) to have a finer grained control on when to upgrade `moduleC`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll edit part of my question, I meant I want to control the part of `+`, the plus version is what's not working, because prefix is matching but there are many versions of suffix, which gradle determines itself. thing is gradle resolves `+` version in some number which doesn't exist and thus dependency fails.

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: That seems really strange. Any chance you can share you build file or parts of it?

Comment: made an edit to add task which is adding dependencies in `compile` configuration on runtime